# SQL Server LDF is is keep growing on secondary Always on

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups

I have configured ALways-On (Async mode) on SQL server 2017, recently LDF file has been growing on secondary (80 GB), but on the primary database it is less than 50 MB, also I have set up full back and transaction log backup on primary (every 30 minutes)

I also have shrunk LDF on primary but LDF on secondary is still growing. to me, size of LDF on primary and secondary should be equal; any thought?

Comment: A shrink operation on a primary is logged and forwarded to secondaries, so it should replay that shrink operation on the secondary. What is the current data latency on your secondary? Any errors in the SQL log on the secondary? It sounds like something is preventing log records from being redone on the secondary so the log file just keeps growing because it can't apply the received log blocks.

Comment: As Handy described earlier every operation is logged and this behavior is not expected on secondary replica.Additionaly you can exclude that database from replica, take log backup from primary side and restore it on secondary to resolve the issue.